# Image carousel collapsing on body

Tags: jquery, html, css

there I am trying to add an [ImageSlider I found online (click here)](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/klkbg) I have added it just below my navigation bar.  I have everything setup, but the images keep collapsing in a descending order on the body instead of going in a carousel mode.   Did I not add javascript correctly?  This is my first time using a jquery

```js
var $item = $('.carousel .item');
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight);
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color': $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  border-width: 1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0b0b0b, #494848);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 77px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Allerta', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100 line-height: 1.7857;
  letter-spacing: .075em;
  float: right !important;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #B9121B;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.full-screen {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mycarousel {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/myExternalFile.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">









  <title> My Website Name</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="nav">

    <img src="logos/navbar-logo.png">

    <li><a class="hover" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Drivers">Drivers</a></li>
  </ul>



  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=397" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=689" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=675" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=658" data-color="lightgreen" alt="Fourth Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Fourth Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=638" data-color="tomato" alt="Fifth Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Fifth Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <script>
    var $item = $('.carousel .item');
    var $wHeight = $(window).height();
    $item.eq(0).addClass('active');
    $item.height($wHeight);
    $item.addClass('full-screen');

    $('.carousel img').each(function() {
      var $src = $(this).attr('src');
      var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
      $(this).parent().css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + $src + ')',
        'background-color': $color
      });
      $(this).remove();
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      $wHeight = $(window).height();
      $item.height($wHeight);
    });

    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000,
      pause: "false"
    });
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I edited your post and with the edit, it seems to be working, check it out

Answer (score 0):

It was just a case of doubled reference to libraries (jQuery). Unless your personal `.js` file does not conflict with this one, it should work as intended.

```js
var $item = $('.carousel .item');
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight);
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color': $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  border-width: 1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0b0b0b, #494848);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 77px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Allerta', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100 line-height: 1.7857;
  letter-spacing: .075em;
  float: right !important;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #B9121B;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.full-screen {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.mycarousel {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/myExternalFile.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">

  <title> My Website Name</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="nav">
    <img src="logos/navbar-logo.png">
    <li><a class="hover" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Drivers">Drivers</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=397" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=689" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=675" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=658" data-color="lightgreen" alt="Fourth Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Fourth Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=638" data-color="tomato" alt="Fifth Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Fifth Image</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: It still seems to collapse when I test out the website.  I even attempted to delete my js file where I had the code written in it, and posted the script in the head yet it still collapses.

Comment: Can you try using only third party scripts and CSS? Maybe they're interfering. Or if you can/wish, post your website?